# Amcharts column is not visible due to huge differences between data points

Tags: javascript, html, graph, charts, amcharts

I am creating a column chart using **Amcharts** , due to huge difference between data points some bars are not visible .

Giving an example with demo datasets you can look .

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 20222
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 10
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 0.4
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 11
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 10
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "labelPosition": "inside",
    "labelRotation": 90,
    "showAllValueLabels": true
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

As in the above data sets

- **Largest value is 20222 for USA**
- **Smallest value is 0.4 For Korea**

Due to this abnormality there are some columns which are not visible but it exists , how to make it visible ?